# How can I turn on basic authentication on a Heroku PHP app?

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku

I have a very simple PHP app that is hosted on Heroku (Cedar Stack). I want to turn on basic authentication but I don't know if it is possible. It doesn't look like it supports .htaccess / .htpasswd but I could be wrong. How can I turn on basic auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bbrewer97202/3316425) it looks like you can add the files you need.

Comment: I will give that a shot tomorrow. I searched everywhere but it looks like that link may have the answer. I'll let you know.